# Make nested list item have a fluid width

Tags: html, css

I want the third-level list items to have fluid widths, so their text should span across a single line, and not be truncated to two lines, as on the snippet.

```css
.menus {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 15px;
}
.menus li {
 list-style: none;
}
.menus > nav > ul > li {
 display: inline-block;
}
.menus li a {
 padding: 10px 25px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 color: #000000;
 text-align: left;

}
.menus > nav > ul > li > ul {
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
 padding: 10px;
 padding-top: 0;
 background: #ffffff;
 text-align: left;
}
.menus > nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
}
.menus > nav > ul > li > ul > li {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 padding: 10px 0;
 margin-left: -10px;
}
.menus > nav > ul > li > ul > li > a {
 padding-right: 25px;
}
.menus > nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 width: auto;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-left: 100%;
 margin-top: -30px;
 background: #ffffff;
 text-align: left;
}
.menus > nav > ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
}
.menus > nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
 display: inline-block;
 width: auto;
}
.menus > nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li a {
 display: block;
 width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="menus">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Hover me</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Hover me too</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Make me fluid, please</a>
              <li><a >Make me fluid too</a></li>
              <li><a href="" >Coming Soon</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Bestsellers</a></li>
              <li><a href="" >Choose What you Pay</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
         </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
 </div>
```

Comment: Your nested `<ul>` has `width:100%`, making it take on the width of its parent. Perhaps try adding `white-space:nowrap` to force it onto a single line?

Comment: Thanks @NiettheDarkAbsol, actually none of the `ul` elements has a width of 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.menus > nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap; // add this
}
```

Comment: Thought about this, but I would really prefer not setting a fixed width for responsiveness. I would love a fluid width, where the line only breaks when it reaches the border of its parent element.

Comment: See my answer, I've changed it for you.

Comment: Yes, `white-space`...never crossed my mind! Thanks :)